# flatfileitemwriter will override the lines before restart job

Tags: spring, csv, spring-batch

As the title said, I use flatfileitemwriter to write data to csv, it ran success when the job completed normally. 
but I have encountered some problem when I test the "retry" function.

the job configurations were as below.

```
<batch:tasklet transaction-manager="resourcelessTransactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="myreader" processor="myprocessor" writer="itemWriter"  commit-interval="40" />
        </batch:tasklet>


<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="file:C:\\xx\\my.csv" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="a,b,c,d" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="forceSync" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And I made the processor throw a exception after it processed 100 records,

```
if(i++ == 100) {
        throw new ProcessException("any way");
    }
```

There are total 300 records need to be handled.
The step I run it was as below.

1. when I run it first time, it will write the first 0-99 records into csv, and throw an expected exception.

   2. when I run it 2nd time, it will write the first 100-199 records into csv, , and throw an expected exception. But the 89-99 records had been overrided.
   3. and the 3rd time, it was just liked the 2nd behavior, the 175-199 had been overrided.

Is there any problem on my code or configuration? The position writer with nio file channel should not be worked like this. How to fix it?

Comment: How about reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setAppendAllowed-boolean-). There you will see a property `append` which default value is `false`... Now imagine what might happen if you toggle that to `true`.

Comment: Append can fix it if I use different file for any job instance, but it does't solved my problem as it was caused by the error position calculation.

Comment: It's so amazing, it was not reappear at home(Jdk8), the only different thing is JDK version, one is 7, any other one is 8.

Comment: Ehrm append will only work if you use the SAME file. If you use a different file for each job instance (assuming you mean the job instance stuff from Spring Batch) it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Append is not worked, since the cursor of file channel has been restored to the wrong position on the method doOpen() before wirte(List). But thank you.

Comment: and append also has another problem,. If I wanna change file path by different job parameters, it will throws an exception that file not writable because it did not create before job.

Comment: The file is perfectly configurable with late binding and a `@StepScope` reader have been using that in different projects. Also I'm not sure why it wouldn't work, are you doing something weird with encodings?

Comment: encoding is always set to UTF-8, and the default value never change.

Comment: and thank you for your reminding, I have found that it was cause by Chinese character, when I convert all Chinese to English or ASCII char, the position calculated right, but how to get the solution? The encoding was already UTF-8

Comment: I found that set transactional as false in flatfileitemwriter is worked, but so ugly.

Comment: Does TransactionAwareBufferedWriter not support Chinese?